# I don't understand the Vivado error: IO placement is infeasible

Tags: constraints, vivado

I have the following Vivado error, which I don't understand:

[Place 30-58] IO placement is infeasible. Number of unplaced terminals (1) is greater than number of available sites (0).
The following are banks with available pins:
IO Group: 0 with : SioStd: LVCMOS18   VCCO = 1.8 Termination: 0  TermDir:  Out  RangeId: 1 Drv: 12  has only 0 sites available on device, but needs 1 sites.
Term: DigOutput[0]

DigOutput, as the name suggests, is a digital output on my block diagram. I don't understand what is meant by "Number of unplaced terminals (1) is greater than number of available sites (0)" in the error message. I am not placing many IOs yet, so I'm definitely not overloading the IOs.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I used "DigOut" in the constraints file instead of "DigOutput". Therefore Vivado couldn't place the IO. I still don't really understand their error message, but at least I solved the problem. The correct definition in the constraints file is:
set_property PACKAGE_PIN G21 [get_ports {DigOutput}]